# WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath not set correcty in VS2015 VC++ variables

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have searched a lot on the web and I couldn't find a proper solution to this, just workarounds. I wonder whether either VS2015 or WindowsSDK installation is broken.

Here is the thing:
I get issue building (in link phase) and the VS environment reports can't find the Resource Compile executable (rc.exe)

`TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "rc.exe". The system cannot find the file specified.`

I searched around on my machine and found the binary in:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64`

So the quick workaround was to add that path to PATH and everything works fine. But I am not really happy about it as I am sure the Windows SDK installer (or VS) should handle this nicely.

If I look into VS IDE -> Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories and look at "Executable Directories" I am expecting to find the right path in there. So I inspect it by opening MACRO (bottom right) and filtering for WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath: there I see

`$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86
$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_arm) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\arm
$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_arm64) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\arm64
$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86
$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64`

As you can see the intel architecture folders point to a generic location (not SDK version specific) that of course doesn't have those binaries. Interestingly enough the ARM folders are correct.

I am trying to understand what has corrupted those folders...

I can guess it's the SDK installer as in the UAP.props file located in

`$(WindowsSDKDir)/DesignTime/CommonConfiguration/Neutral/UAP/10.0.16299.0/`

I can see this

`<WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86>$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\x86;</WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86>
<WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64>$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\x64;</WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64>`

although I am not 100% sure as this is post-install so it could be VS changing that.

Any ideas? Suggestions? Anyone who had the same issue and managed to find a proper fix instead of workarounds?

Comment: BTW this works as expected in VS 2017, the executable points to the right location. I guess by looking that the way it is set in the UAP.props that WindowsSDKDir itself might be wrong or not updated

Comment: A project that uses an .rc file should have its Target Platform Version set to 8.1.  Targeting one of the many 10.0.x versions is only necessary for UWP apps.  Which don't use .rc

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your comment. That would explain a lot. Where can I find in-depth documentation about this? I've searched around but I found Microsoft forums really confusing

Comment: @HansPassant When you target 8.1 you get a rather old `libucrt.lib` version. The only clean way to get a current `libucrt.lib` that we found is to switch to a newer Windows 10 SDK. Which then causes this error.

Answer (score 1):

Right, not sure if this is the right one but digging a bit on the issue brought me at this point. What I have found is this strange block of xml code in

`$(WindowsSDKDir)\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.16299.0\UAP.props`

that looks like this:

```html
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' != '' and '$(VisualStudioVersion)' &lt;= '14.0'">
  <WDKBinRoot>$(WindowsSdkDir)bin</WDKBinRoot>
  <WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86>$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\x86;</WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86>
  <WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64>$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\x64;</WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' &gt; '14.0'">
  <WDKBinRoot>$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\10.0.16299.0</WDKBinRoot>
  <WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86>$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\10.0.16299.0\x86;</WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86>
  <WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64>$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\10.0.16299.0\x64;</WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Correct me if I am wrong but that doesn't seem to do anything in case you have VS2015 (which is 14.0)

So I appended this after that block:

```html
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '14.0'">
  <WDKBinRoot>$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\10.0.16299.0</WDKBinRoot>
  <WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86>$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\10.0.16299.0\x86;</WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86>
  <WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64>$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\10.0.16299.0\x64;</WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64>
</PropertyGroup>
```

With that change all works. I wonder why this file is populated this way. If you look at the end it includes arm and desktop.arm props. I also wonder if I can create a property file separate to this generic UAP.props.

Of course this fixes only this specific SDK version, you will have to do it for every version installed and, if you install a new one.